# Search terms on sentences with python

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, matching, text-mining

I have several sentences stored in MongoDB, and several dictionaries of terms (each term is composed of one or more words). I want search terms on sentences, but it is really slow to try matching for each term in each sentence, and this will be exact matching. How could I do easily to do a fuzzy matching or something like this to find my terms on sentences?

For example,

Sentence:

Ala394Thr polymorphism in the clock gene NPAS2: a circadian modifier for the risk of non-Hodgkin's lymphoma

Dictionary:

Ala394Thr | NPAS-2 | Lymphoma of Hodgkin

And the result should be:

**Ala394Thr** polymorphism in the clock gene **NPAS2**: a circadian modifier for the risk of non-**Hodgkin's lymphoma**

Comment: Add some example documents, that makes it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I probably would suggest you have a look at dedicated search engines such as Solr or ElasticSearch. They are much better suited for this sort of task.

Have a look at https://github.com/renctan/mongo-solr on how to do this with oplog tailing.

Comment: Is it possible to combine Solr or ElasticSearch with mongoDB?

Comment: Of course, you will just have to push all changes into Solr and ElasticSearch as well.